# Databases 'performance_schema' and 'sql' missing after the reinstallation of mysql

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, vps

We are working on an important website, our VPS has shutdown and reopened after 2 days by OVH. After that we have not been able to access our phpmyadmin and been obligated to reinstall mysql-client and mysql-server + phpmyadmin. But at the installation we got alot of errors, it's when we discover that we have not the databases performance_schema and sql that we understand that's going bad. We have navigated during 1 hour to search for a solution, but nothing works, we have killed, clean and reinstall the mysql again and again and nothing works more now.

Thanks for the future answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is seriously wrong with your installation procedure.  The `mysql` and `performance_schema` "databases" aren't really databases. They are built in to the MySQL server software. If they are missing it's a sign that your installation is -- disastrously -- incorrect.  But you know that.

I suspect you're using a nonstandard procedure for reinstalling the mysql server. Are you trying to install it in a way which doesn't overwrite your `data` directory? You Can't Do That™.  Try a completely fresh installation of the MySQL server, then restore database backups.

(Notice that your installations of MySQL client software and phpmyadmin are not related to this problem.)

Comment: Ok, but I have done a completely fresh installation but nothing work more, Do I need to reinstall my complete VPS? PS: no I don't try to install with a way which it doesn't overwrite my data.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need 'performance_schema'?

I would reinstall the vps with debian 7/8 and try it again.